# Unloading Large Sql Anywhere Table

Tags: data-migration, sqlanywhere, long-running-processes

1. An old box has brought back live running Sql Anywhere 9.
2. I need to retrieve data from there to migrate to SQL Server and then I can kill the old box again

I ran an unload on 533 tables which all run ok. I have 1 table that does not unload.

I run the dbunload from the command-line and since it worked for 533 tables... in theory it should work.

I dont see specific what is wrong with this table. The unload runs but gives no errors (and also no file is written). I checked the event log and also no errors. I just wonder how to diagnose the problem to check what is wrong. One thing I do notice is that this the only table without a primary key, but I dont know if this matters with unload.

the production database of this table contains 50.000.000 entries. The archive version only contains 15 million entries but both versions refuse to be unloaded or better said: give no indication of what is wrong but simply dont generate an unloaded file.

I wonder if it is the size that is the problem, maybe memory / temp diskspace? or otherwise a time-out that is set somewhere.

I also wonder if there is an alternative.

p.s. the gui (sybase central) just produces an endless turning wheel that never finishes.

update: i saw that dbunload works temp in the user's local settings/temp directory. Possible that is why it fails or there is possible some other place where it temporary saves items.